# Grails word separating

Tags: grails

I am using a  to take param from user after that I want to separate the strings to check that words are existing or not in my database. What code/algorithm I should use to separate words from a string param?

Comment: You need to rephrase your question, as it is not clear what question you exactly want to ask. `a` is a variable here?

Comment: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions You mean this?

Answer (score 0):

You should send the words as an array parameter, e.g.

```
?word=hello&word=world&word=something&word=else
```

In a controller you can retrieve the words as a list of strings with

```
List<String> allWords = params.list('word')
```